# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error' what() numpy failed to initialize

Tags: docker, numpy, devops, python-3.8, ubuntu-20.04

**Environment:** Docker Image based on nvidia/cuda:11.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu20.04, python3.8, numpy==1.19.4, opencv=3.4.3.

---

**Error:** `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error' what() numpy failed to initialize`, `RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd`

---

**This solution helped:**
`pip3 install --upgrade numpy`
(Successfully installed numpy-1.23.0)

---

**Description:**
The python3 application runs successfully with the specified initial version of numpy on a host ubuntu20.04.4.
However, when run in docker based on the same Ubuntu release, it stops at the indicated error.
The solution is found, in the indicated form. However, the essence of the question why this difference in the numpy versions on the host and inside the docker container has a place, is so remains unclear.

**Question:**
Why this difference in numpy versions on the host (1.19.4) and inside the docker container (1.23.0) has a place, if all the rest of the environment looks identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pycuda is a package that compiles; when it compiles, it uses numpy's libraries.

Next solution, allowed me to use ***required*** version of numpy:

```
pip3 uninstall pycuda -y
pip3 install --upgrade numpy==1.19.4
pip3 install pycuda==2019.1
```